# How to fill ACF fields using Wordpress Rest-Api in Python

Tags: python, json, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to fill ACF Fields using Wordpress Rest-Api in Python, but when I try to make request it's giving "400 Bad Request". I'm using ACF latest verison 5.11 that comes with in-built api integration.

This is my code, please help me to solve this problem.

```
import requests
import json
import base64

url = "example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"

user = "exmaple@gmail.com"
password = "RIHr O7kE SCn0 LXVW xyPc jBn9"

credentials = user + ':' + password

token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}
post = {
 "title"    : "Hello World",
 "type"     : "post",
 "status"   : "publish", 
 "content"  : "This is my first post created using rest API",
 "acf" : {
     "youtube_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0outb6oSJW4"
 }
}
responce = requests.post(url , headers=header, json=post)
print(responce.status_code, responce.reason)
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things to check/change here

1. In your functions.php file in WordPress, ensure you've registered the post meta. For example

```
function function_name() {   
    register_meta('post', 'youtube_url',
        [
            'object_subtype' => 'post',
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'single' => true,
            'type' => 'string',
            'auth_callback' => function() {
                return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
            }
        ]
    );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'function_name' );
```

2 then update...

```
 "acf" : {
     "youtube_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0outb6oSJW4"
 }
```

to...

```
 "meta" : {
     "youtube_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0outb6oSJW4"
 }
```

3 And finally, in the field group settings in ACF, ensure 'Show in REST API' is selected